# Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 2017 registry

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

Did registry paths change for the Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 2017?

Before we were able to locate instance name here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\RS\MSSQLSERVER
```

But now in 2017 **MSSQLSERVER** is missing and it has **SSRS** instead.

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server) article it should be still under **MSSQLSERVER** but it's not. Did we missed some installation setting that caused this or this is default standard behavior now?

Answer (score 1):

Because Reporting Services is now a separate installation, it installs as a named instance `SSRS`. This is a change from previous versions where Reporting Services was part of SQL Server setup.

I would suggest using WMI queries to obtain the necessary information (example below using PowerShell). Notice that the v14 refers to the 2017 release.

```
$wmiName = (Get-WmiObject –namespace root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer  –class __Namespace).Name
$rsConfig = Get-WmiObject –namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\$wmiName\v14\Admin" -class MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old but I had the same problem in my company to find information from RS 2017 and found no place that reported the right location so I wanted to post here!

My friend (Paulo Henrique Rodrigues Orind) and I found a place where you can get all the information about the RS 2017 and I hope the RS 2019 is the same.

**1) By PowerShell + WMI:**

```
Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ReportServer\RS_SSRS\V14" -class MSReportServer_Instance | Select-Object -Property EditionName, Version, InstanceName
```

[Image-powerShellCommand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1sg2.png)

**2) By C# + WMI (Do you will need to import the System.Management.dll)**

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("Root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ReportServer\\RS_SSRS\\V14", options);
            scope.Connect();

            //Query system for Operating System information
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM MSReportServer_Instance");
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
            {
                // Display the remote computer information
                Console.WriteLine("EditionName       : {0}", m["EditionName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("EditionID         : {0}", m["EditionID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("InstanceID        : {0}", m["InstanceID"]);
                Console.WriteLine("InstanceName      : {0}", m["InstanceName"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Version           : {0}", m["Version"]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

[Image-CsharpCode-Wmi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLkPJ.png)

**3) WMI:**

[wmi_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BamUo.png)

[wmi_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbucr.png)

[wmi_3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYw9A.png)

[wmi_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RSvW.png)

Opening the WMI: 
Namespace: Root >> Microsoft >> SqlServer >> ReportServer >> RS_SSRS >> V14
Class: MSReportServer_Instance

I hope I have helped with something